# How to include session in my custom lib file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know I will get answers that I shouldn't do this, but due to specific way to solve problem I am facing, I will have to use session in my /lib/example.rb file. (or at least I think I will have to use it)

I am calling an action, which will first run (seudo code):

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def funcion(value)
    MyClass.use_this(value)
  end
end
```

And then I will use it in my `lib/example.rb`

```
module MyClass
  # include SessionsHelper # this is not working

  def self.use_this(value)
    # I want to be able to use session here. What I need to do that in order to make it work.
    session[:my_value] = value
  end
end
```

What should I do in order to use session inside MyClass (I can pass variable to `MyClass.use_this(value,session)`, but I wouldn't want to do that

Edit:

What I want to achieve with this `session` thing is that I would like to preserve a value during multiple requests. I am making a call to the web application multiple times, and I want to preserve some value on the next call. I am calling the app via API and I shouldn't use database to save values. So I have left with sessions, or text files, or even maybe cookies to make this happen - to preserve the same value on multiple calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not include the module in your controller, and then call the `use_this` function directly from there?

```
module MyClass #should probably rename this anyway
  def use_this(value)
    session[:my_value] = value
  end
end

class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include MyClass

  def some_action
    ...
    use_this(the_value)
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I am using some class as an intermediate class between these two classes. I haven't mentioned in the question as thought it might be something simple that I am missing

Comment: `session` is a method defined by the controller base class in rails, there is no simple way to make it accessible outside the class without  doing something like i've done, or passing it as a method parameter.

Comment: well, that is an answer that might help me (or at least to give up on searching :) ) and to use parameters or something similar to that.

Comment: If you post some more code in your question, or explain a bit more about what you're trying to achieve, you might get better help.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the answer with what I want to achieve.

Comment: I had figured that much out already :), can you explain why my suggestion does not suit?

Comment: It suits well. Even more your comment suits me more :) I have gave it +1 ;) I didn't want to give accepted answer just yet, as who knows who will write an answer. I will check some things in my code, and I will return to accept it

Answer (score -1):

In order to use session inside MyClass may be you could use instance variable @session:

```
module MyClass
  extend SessionsHelper

  def self.use_this(value)
    @session[:my_value] = value
  end
end

module SessionsHelper
  def some_method
    @session = ...
  end
end
```

**self.include(module)** method makes the instance methods (and instance variables) of the included module into instance methods of the including module.

Edit: *include SessionsHelper* changed to *extend SessionsHelper*

**self.extend(module)** -- methods of receiver become class methods of that class and instance variables will work between this methods.

Comment: since use_this is a class method, the instance variable will not be accessible to some_method

Comment: Yeah, you are right, if you want to make some_method as a class method of that class (MyClass) then you should use 'extend SessionsHelper' instead of 'include SessionsHelper'. Then instance variable will be accessible between this methods.